# Gatling csv feeders

Tags: csv, gatling

I am migrating from gatling 1.5 to 2.14. 
In 1.5, I have address.csv with one column city_name.I have a ssp template in request-bodies folder and i manipulate the value  using <%= cityName >.Below is my scenario.

```
val myAddress = csv(address.csv).random
val scn = scenario("myRequest"){
  feed(myAddress).exec ( http(myRequest)..post("")
                                .headers(headers_1)
                                .fileBody(requestName,
          Map("cityName" -> "${city_name}"))
                                .check(status.is(200)))
```

In 2.14, i am following the migration guide and using ELFileBody but confused about how to map the fields.Any help would be appreciated

```
val myAddress = csv(address.csv).random
val scn = scenario("myRequest"){
  feed(myAddress).exec ( http(myRequest).post("")
                                .headers(headers_1)
                                 .body(ELFileBody((requestName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer have to do this cumbersome mapping. Those new templates are directly plugged to the Session, you just have to use regular expression language.

Comment: Replaced with regex in my ssp template with the name matching my column and it works. It is great that we dont have to worry about mapping as i have multiple columns. Thanks